# Linebreak causes code to break

Tags: php, javascript, line, break

I have a text stored in database (after it was inputted by user in textarea).

The text includes break line tags.

Now I'm importing it to my php page and do the following thing:

```
$str += "onclick='openXXX(\"" . nl2br($row->data)  .  "\");'>"
```

Now in the view it breaks my code because there are `<BR>` and `\r\n` chars (I think), 
and it looks as:

```
onclick='openXXX("dsadas<br />
dsada");'
```

it's causing to problem in my code because there are two line instead of one. How can I solve it?

Comment: I could be wrong but I think the `<br />` needs escaping when passed to a javascript function, `<br \/>`

Comment: I managed to run the onclick event with: str_replace("\n","", str_replace("\r","",htmlentities(nl2br($row->data)))) but now I have an another problem: when the text is shown in the textarea it looks as: dsadas<br /> dsada .   what should I use in JS in order to switch it to real BRs?

Comment: Eventually I've solved it by replace(new RegExp("<br />", "g"), "\r\n"). Without RegExp it will effect the first occurrence only. Thanks for you all efforts!

Answer (score 3):

use

```
str_replace('\r\n', '', nl2br($row->data))
```

Comment: your code is an illegal and furthermore it's removing the break lines in the textarea and I have to show breaks.

Comment: then you should escape new line character and pass as parameter. you should replace newline character in openXXX function after they are passed as escaped. that's the solution.

Comment: I managed to run the onclick event with: str_replace("\n","", str_replace("\r","",htmlentities(nl2br($row->data)))) but now I have an another problem: when the text is shown in the textarea it looks as: dsadas<br /> dsada . what should I use in JS in order to switch it to real BRs?

Comment: assume that your string is "str", try this code `str = str.replace("<br />", "\r\n");`

Comment: replace(new RegExp("<br />", "g"), "\r\n") the solution

Answer (score 2):

Javascript does not take in newline, you can consider this :-

```
str_replace(PHP_EOL, '', nl2br($row->data));
```

beside `PHP_EOL`, you can replace it with an array of `\r\n, \n\r, \n and \r`

Answer (score 2):

Try `str_replace('\n', '', nl2br($row->data))` instead of just `nl2br($row->data)`.

Comment: Odd, it worked for me. Try preg_replace("%\n%", "<br />", $row->data) instead.

Answer (score 2):

nl2br is adding the `<br/>`, but not removing the \r or \n.

Try:

```
$str += "onclick='openXXX(\"" . str_replace(array("\r","\n"),'',nl2br($row->data))  .  "\");'>"
```